# How to read the result of Flow in Android Compose @Composable function for non-GUI consumption (e.g. for writing in repository)

Tags: repository, android-jetpack-compose, coroutinescope, android-jetpack-datastore

I am introducing DataStore in my Android Compose app for storing user preferences. While I am not happy about keeping the DataStore instance as a attribute of Context instance - because the Context is accessible from the @Composable only (and not in, e.g. repository) - I am still going for it.

Lets assume (following the references tutorial), that `getEmail` is the function that reads the DataStore key-value pair and that returns the Flow instance.

My intention is to put the following (approxiamte) code into one of my top-level @Composable, which has AppContainer as an argument - such composables are very top level:

```
var email = getEmail.collectAsState("") //or should I use single()?
appContainer.salesOrderRespository.setEmail(email)
```

But I am afraid to do this in this very crude way in which I have wrote this above. E.g. I am concerned about the following things:

1. should I put this code in some scope (because its collectAsState can block the GUI thread), like:

   *val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
   scope.launch {
   var email = getEmail.collectAsState("") //or should I use single()?
   appContainer.salesOrderRespository.setEmail(email)

   }*
2. Can I use construction `var email = getEmail.collectAsState("")` - email can not be accessible immediately, it is assigned asynchronously. That is why I may need something like this (just imagination):

   *getEmail.collectAsState("").onReadingDone( it - > { appContainer.salesOrderRespository.setEmail(it) })*
3. And, of course, I am eager to execute this code as early as possible. Almost of my repositories are in need of configuration data and if application is starting and going ahead while still reading the configuration data from the DataStore, then the app will not work as expected.

So - I am trying to to just one thing - read DataStore (**1.** **as attribute of the Context**, because there is no other proper global instance to whom I can create such attribute; **2.** **inside @Composable**, because Context can be accessed from the @Composable only) and assigne the read value to the attributes of one or more repositories. But I observed that this operation is very complex and involved many concerns. I listed them. That is my question is quite long and complex, but it effectively tries to tackle one simple thing only - reading+assigning.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use the Context helper. Instead, I would look into integrating Hilt and injecting your data store into your repository.

Here is a blog about the technique.
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/datastore-and-dependency-injection-ea32b95704e3

Comment: I am thinking about this pretty much, but I am concerned about one thing - (as I understand) the developer can inject pretty everything in pretty every class using the injection and I am concerned whether I can violate something, some architectural principles etc. That can lead to subtle bugs, to bad design (spaghetti code) etc. If there were some best-practices guidelines available for injection (what is appropriate and what is not) then I would feel more safe to follow this path... OK, most likely I will open additional question for such guidelines... Maybe in software engineering stack.

Comment: For that, check out our android architecture guide. https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture